# PDDL - The Goat, Wolf and the Cabbage

Tags: artificial-intelligence, river-crossing-puzzle, pddl

I've been asked to write a solution to the famous "Goat, Wolf and the Cabbage" scernario. The scenario goes as follows:

The farmer wants to transport all three across the river. However, if:

- The goat and the cabbage are left alone, the goat will eat the cabbage
- IF the wolf and the goat are left alone, the wolf will eat the goat!

So one solution to the problem is as follows:

- Take the goat across the river, and drop it on the other side
- Come back across the river
- Pick up EITHER the cabbage or the wolf, and bring it to the other side
- Drop off the wolf, pick up the goat, and go back to the other side
- Drop off the goat, pick up the cabbage, and go back to the other side
- Pick up the goat, and voila! All three are transported.

However, I'm having trouble projecting this into PDDL. I've been give the problem definition:

```
(define 
(problem boat1)
(:domain boat)
; only needs two objects, namely representing
; either banke side of the river, [w]est and [e]ast
(:objects  w e)
(:INIT 
    ; wolf, goat, cabbage, boat are all on 
    ; the west side to start with
    (config w w w w)

    ; represent all valid states
    ; these two are the special case,
    ; representing that wolf and cabbage are
    ; safe together even if the boat is away
    (valid w e w e)
    (valid e w e w)

    ; these are all cases where two entities
    ; are always safe as long as the boat is 
    ; with them. In other words, a single entity
    ; on the other side is also always safe
    ; for west side
    (valid w w w w)
    (valid w w e w)
    (valid w e w w)
    (valid e w w w)
    ; for east side
    (valid e e e e)
    (valid e e w e)
    (valid e w e e)
    (valid w e e e)
    ; these are all valid states that are
    ; ever allowed


)

(:goal (AND 
        ; they all have to move to the east side
        (config e e e e)
    )
)
```

Finally, we've been given only 1 predicate, and have been told that this can be done with 4 actions. Move_empty, move_goat, move_wolf, move_cabbage.

The predicate is:

(config ?wolf ?goat ?cabbage ?boat)
(valid ?wolf ?goat ?cabbage ?boat)

and I've tried to start on move_empty with:

```
    (:action move_empty
     :parameters (?from ?to)
     :precondition (and (valid ?x ?y ?z ?w) (on_left ?from) (on_right ?to))                      
     :effect (and (valid ?x ?y ?z ?w)))
```

I do not wish for answers, only help and advice on how to solve this as there is not a lot of information on PDDL, from what I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** I don't know the **pddl** language, this is what I achieved by looking at your code.

---

**MAIN IDEA**

In your problem, each entity is described as either being on the *west* or *east* bank of the river and entities are identified using their relative position within the predicates *config* and *valid*.

Each *action* starts from a given *configuration* and must end into another *configuration*. In addition, we must require the **end** *configuration* to be *valid*.

So *move_empty* from the *east* to the *west* side of the bank is as simple as:

```
  (:action move_empty_ew :parameters (?x ?y ?z)
   :precondition (and (config ?x ?y ?z e) (valid ?x ?y ?z w))
   :effect (and (not (config ?x ?y ?z e)) (config ?x ?y ?z w))
  )
```

Here, we let the positions of all other entities (the wolf, the goat and the cabbage) to be undetermined, while we require that initially the *boat* is on the *east* bank and that letting the *boat* go to the *west* bank while leaving the animals unattended is a *valid* move. If all these conditions are met, then we move to the desired configuration.

---

**SOLUTION**

Notice that i refined the name of the actions so that they are more informative wrt. the actual action that is being taken.

**boat-domain.pddl**

```
(define (domain boat)
  (:requirements :equality)

  (:predicates
    (config ?wolf ?goat ?cabbage ?boat)
    (valid ?wolf ?goat ?cabbage ?boat)
  )

  (:action move_empty_ew :parameters (?x ?y ?z)
   :precondition (and (config ?x ?y ?z e) (valid ?x ?y ?z w))
   :effect (and (not (config ?x ?y ?z e)) (config ?x ?y ?z w))
  )
  (:action move_empty_we :parameters (?x ?y ?z)
   :precondition (and (config ?x ?y ?z w) (valid ?x ?y ?z e))
   :effect (and (not (config ?x ?y ?z w)) (config ?x ?y ?z e))
  )

  (:action move_wolf_ew :parameters (?y ?z)
   :precondition (and (config e ?y ?z e) (valid w ?y ?z w))
   :effect (and (not (config e ?y ?z e)) (config w ?y ?z w))
  )
  (:action move_wolf_we :parameters (?y ?z)
   :precondition (and (config w ?y ?z w) (valid e ?y ?z e))
   :effect (and (not (config w ?y ?z w)) (config e ?y ?z e))
  )

  (:action move_goat_ew :parameters (?x ?z)
   :precondition (and (config ?x e ?z e) (valid ?x w ?z w))
   :effect (and (not (config ?x e ?z e)) (config ?x w ?z w))
  )
  (:action move_goat_we :parameters (?x ?z)
   :precondition (and (config ?x w ?z w) (valid ?x e ?z e))
   :effect (and (not (config ?x w ?z w)) (config ?x e ?z e))
  )

  (:action move_cabbage_ew :parameters (?x ?y)
   :precondition (and (config ?x ?y e e) (valid ?x ?y w w))
   :effect (and (not (config ?x ?y e e)) (config ?x ?y w w))
  )
  (:action move_cabbage_we :parameters (?x ?y)
   :precondition (and (config ?x ?y w w) (valid ?x ?y e e))
   :effect (and (not (config ?x ?y w w)) (config ?x ?y e e))
  )
)
```

**boat-prob.pddl**

```
(define (problem boat)
  (:domain boat)
  (:objects w e)

  (:INIT (config w w w w)
    (valid w e w e) (valid e w e w)
    (valid w w w w) (valid w w e w)
    (valid w e w w) (valid e w w w)
    (valid e e e e) (valid e e w e)
    (valid e w e e) (valid w e e e)
  )

  (:goal (config e e e e))
)
```

I used **fast-downward** to find a minimum-length solution:

```
~$ fast-downward.py --alias seq-opt-bjolp boat-domain.pddl boat-prob.pddl
```

which actually is:

```
move_goat_we w w (1)
move_empty_ew w e w (1)
move_cabbage_we w e (1)
move_goat_ew w e (1)
move_wolf_we w e (1)
move_empty_ew e w e (1)
move_goat_we e e (1)
Plan length: 7 step(s).
Plan cost: 7
```